# why this url can't match Route Temple in asp.net webapi

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2

Why this url(http://localhost:52806/openapi/Icrmorder.TestApi/) can match route temple(openapi/I{controller}.{action}/)
but url(http://localhost:52806/IRegion.TestApi/) didn't?

this is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.4
 I had google and try all condition,Still no result,I need some help,Ths!

1.WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TestRegion
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API 配置和服务

            // Web API 路由
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "openapi/I{controller}.{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

2.RegionController.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TestRegion.Controllers
{
    public class RegionController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult TestApi()
        {
            return Json( new { value="ceshi" });
        }
    }
}
```

3. CrmOrderController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TestRegion.Controllers
{
    public class CrmOrderController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult TestApi()
        {
            return Json(new { value = "ceshi" });
        }
    }
}
```

result：
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 is that you have a `.` in your route template so your configuration will need to have:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

if you're hosting on HTTP.SYS (ex: ISIS) and you don't have that already.

Issue 2 *may* be a limitation of Web API. I'm not sure if you can have two route parameters in the same URL segment. Theoretically it should be possible, but I've never seen such a route template before.

Finally, your route configuration indicates that it has an optional `{id}` route parameter that isn't even in the route template. This *shouldn't* affect the results, but its configuration is meaningless and arguably confusing to a reviewer.

I would consider removing the `.` from your route template and further consider using a more conventional route template that has a form closer to `{controller}/{action}`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to get rid of the past ```.```,routeTemple like this  ```openapi/I{controller}/{action}/``` problem still.But I geted rid of the past ```I``` or change to ```other```,routeTemple like this (ex: ```openapi/{controller}.{action}/ ```,```openapi/other{controller}.{action}/ ```and It work well.So I guess it is related to the route prefix ```I``` .Is that a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure why the `I` prefix would matter. It's possible it's a bug, but it would be down in Web API itself. I would be surprised if it was limited to `I`. You might experiment with a different, single-letter prefix to see if you get the same result. Interesting that `openapi/other{controller}.{action}` works. That does suggest there may be something wrong with the template parsing.

Comment: single-letter prefix （ex:```openapi/A{controller}.{action}/``` can work well

Comment: Interesting. So it works with `A` as a prefix, but not `I`? I'm not sure why that should matter. Were you ultimately able to get things working the way you want?